# Ruby on rails with Badgateway issue and mailer ( using mailgun ).

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-ec2

I'm Ruby user! My amazon EC2 server went into "502 Badgateway" at exactly X:00 suddenly.

At that timing, a mailer function was expected to be run. ( and it was ).

The system started to send an email but the system was stopped. I went to Mailgun service log and there was one email that was not sent ( error message ).

I didn't use "begin-rescue" format when running mailer.

```
every :tuesday, :at => '1pm' do
    runner "User.email_tutor_apply" #확인
end

###below is a mail function.

def self.email_tutor_apply 

 @user = User.where(:role => 1).where(:mock_session_passed => true)
 @user.each do |user|
   wowmailer.tutor_apply(user).deliver_now
 end
```

Do you guys think that this was caused by mailgun issue because i didn't use 'begin-rescue' statement?

If something went wrong, I assumed that the page would lead me to "Something went wrong" instead of burning the server.

When is the case the server went to "502 Badgateway" permanently in EC2 ( NGNIX )?

Please let me know. !!

Comment: Are you sending emails through mailguns http post option or using their stmp gateway?

Comment: I'm sending an email using STMP gateway! The setting is done in config/production.rb file!

Comment: Can you post a snippet from your rails log file near where that 502 is being rendered and what errors its spitting out?